# Is this a valid way to find Kernel and Image?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

My lecturer this semester explains things really bad, so us students have to teach ourselves. Someone found this way to get Im(A) and Ker(A). Is it correct?

We have matrix A.

For Kernel:

Solve the homogeneous problem for matrix A and for each parameter you have in the solution vector, you get a vector in which that parameter is 1 and the others are 0. The span of those vectors is the Kernel.

For Image:

Get Aᵀ (A transposed) to rref form and take the span of all the rows that are not a row of 0s.

Do these work? I really want to make sure they do before our final test.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be thinking about this very mechanistically.  What is your current understanding of the meaning of "kernel" and "image?"

Comment: Kernal is the group of vectors that when put through the transformation A will give you the 0 vector. Image is the group of vectors that are present after the transformation A.
I know I'm trying think algorithmically. That's how I do math. I memorize how to do stuff, and separate that from my genuine intuition for the subject.

Comment: As the above answer indicates, the methods describe will work fine.  However, it should be fairly obvious that they work, or else you do not really have an effective understanding of both of the definitions that you have just given.

Have you tried to construct a vector that would be generated by the procedure, that does not match the definition?  Have you tried to find a vector that fits the definition that the procedure does not generate?

Comment: The kernal one was obvious, it's basically simple logic. But the image one was weird for me, since other than this, I never heard about transposing THEN doing RREF.
I did try some examples to see if it works. I just want to make sure.

Comment: The only way to be sure is to understand why the procedure generates the correct answer.  You can't separate this from your intuitive understanding of the subject.

Part of why this is tricky (and which is why you're hung up on the transpose) is that it depends on whether you adopt the standard of multiplying on the left or on the right.  The only thing that's robust to this is a rigorous understanding of what the symbols *represent*.

Comment: Do you know that matrix transformations are linear? Do you know about [row and column spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces) of a matrix? In particular, $\operatorname{im}A$ is the column space of $A$ (which is the same as the row space of $A^t$; you don't need to put it in RREF form, that is done only to ensure that you aren't using any vectors that are redundant to the spanning process by removing linearly dependent vectors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying a row operation on an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ is left multiplication by a certain invertible matrix $E$. $\ker(EA) = \ker(A)$, so row operations preserve the kernel.

Applying a column operation on $A$ is right multiplication by a certain invertible matrix $C$. $\text{im}(AC) = \text{im}(A)$, so column operations preserve the image. Doing column operations on $A$ is the same as transposing $A$, doing row operations, then transposing it back. So your method will work.

Comment: Thanks! Just one thing: why is it clear that the elementary matrices preserve the Im() and ker()? Doesn't seem obvious to me, personally.
Other than that, This explanation is great. So thanks.

Comment: @Remeraze Right it isn't obvious, but it is easy to prove. It is a good exercise in using the definitions of $\ker$ and $\text{im}$. For example, if $Av = 0$, then $EAv = E0 = 0$. Thus $\ker(A) \subset \ker(EA)$. If $EAv = 0$, then injectivity of $E$ implies $Av = 0$. Thus $\ker(EA) \subset \ker(A)$. Thus $\ker(A) = \ker(EA)$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!